# How can i put $variable into array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, echo

Hello this is the code i want to put an variable into array

```
    class NewTest extends BaseExample {
  public function render() {
    $startDate = $this->getNow();
    $endDate = $this->getNow();
    $optParams = array(
      'metric' => array('EARNINGS'),
      'useTimezoneReporting' => true,
      'filter' => 'DOMAIN_NAME==' .$sub. ',      
    );
```

I've tried `' .$sub.'` and $sub but it doesn't work

Comment: You're missing a `'` at the end of the filter line.

Answer (score 0):

Minor syntax error - just had to remove the final `. '`

```
class NewTest extends BaseExample {
  public function render() {
   $startDate = $this->getNow();
   $endDate = $this->getNow();
   $optParams = array(
    'metric' => array('EARNINGS'),
    'useTimezoneReporting' => true,
    'filter' => 'DOMAIN_NAME==' . $sub,      
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: This is the error I get http://misviral.com/adsense/mostawesomeposts.com/examples/adsense/?sub=travel.misviral.com&action=NewTest

Answer (score 0):

A `'` is missing

```
'filter' => 'DOMAIN_NAME==' .$sub. '',
```

Since it is useless this should be better

```
'filter' => 'DOMAIN_NAME==' .$sub,
```

Comment: This is the error I get http://misviral.com/adsense/mostawesomeposts.com/examples/adsense/?sub=travel.misviral.com&action=NewTest

Answer (score 0):

> remove the '

```
    class NewTest extends BaseExample {
  public function render() {
    $startDate = $this->getNow();
    $endDate = $this->getNow();
    $optParams = array(
      'metric' => array('EARNINGS'),
      'useTimezoneReporting' => true,
      'filter' => 'DOMAIN_NAME==' .$sub,      
    );
```